# Ansible: Lookup variables dynamically in v2.3

Tags: variables, dynamic, ansible, lookup, ansible-2.x

I have a set of variables and a task as follows. My intent is to dynamically do a healthcheck based on the URL the user chose.

```
vars:
  current_hostname: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
  hc_url1: "https://blah1.com/healthcheck"
  hc_url2: "https://blah2.com/healthcheck"

tasks:
- name: Notification Msg For Healthcheck
  shell: "echo 'Performing healthcheck at the URL {{ lookup('vars', component) }} on host {{ current_hostname }}'"
```

Run playbook in Ansible 2.3

```
ansible-playbook ansible_playbook.yml -i inventory -k -v --extra-vars "component=hc_url1"
```

Error

```
fatal: [hostname]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "lookup plugin (vars) not found"}
```

I know this happens because lookup plugin "var" was introduced in Ansible v2.5. Is there a way to do this in Ansible 2.3? I want get the value of {{ component }}, and then the value of {{ hc_url1 }}

PS - upgrading to 2.5 is not an option because of org restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, maybe you can do this using a dictionary.

For example,

```
vars:
  current_hostname: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
  urls:
    hc_url1: "https://blah1.com/healthcheck"
    hc_url2: "https://blah2.com/healthcheck"

tasks:
- name: Notification Msg For Healthcheck
  shell: "echo 'Performing healthcheck at the URL {{ urls[component] }} on host {{ current_hostname }}'"
```

That way, the user provided value of `component` will just be looked up as a key in the dictionary.